# Dynamically get instruction size in bytes using ptrace

Tags: assembly, x86, ptrace

I am using `ptrace` to follow a process and monitor its behavior. At some point I would like to get the next `rip` address before hitting the next instruction. In fact, I would like to call get the address of the instruction following a `callq` instruction. There are a few different such instructions (near, far, relative, absolute etc) and they don't all have the same length.

Is there a way using `ptrace` to get the size in bytes of the instruction, once the instruction has been retrieved. Something like the following:

```
int ip = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, t_pid, ipoffs, 0);                    // some addr where ip points
long isntruction = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, t_pid, ip, NULL);           // e8 ae 72 f8 ff (relative call)
printf("Instruction is %d bytes", get_instruction_size(instruction));  // Instrction is 5 bytes
```

I am guessing one way to implement `get_instruction_size` would be to get the opcode (first 1 or 2 bytes) of the instruction and then determine how long it should be according to the x86 architecture/manual. But I feel like there will be a lot of special cases to take into account and a lot of reading around to find the values + this will change from one CPU architecture to another. On the other hand dynamically finding the size seems much more convenient. I have not found an answer to this.

------ EDIT -------

Trying to retrieve the return value from rsp right after a call:

```
#define M_OFFSETOF(STRUCT, ELEMENT) \
        (unsigned long) &((STRUCT *)NULL)->ELEMENT;
...
ipoffs = M_OFFSETOF(struct user, regs.rip);
spoffs = M_OFFSETOF(struct user, regs.rsp);
...
while(1) {
    // exec one instruction
    if(ptrace(PTRACE_SINGLESTEP, t_pid, 0, signo) < 0){
        perror("ptrace single step error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ip = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, t_pid, ipoffs, 0);
    full_instruction = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, t_pid, ip, NULL);
    opcode = (unsigned)0xFF & full_instruction;
    if(opcode == ADDR32){
        opcode = ((unsigned)0xFF00 & full_instruction) >> 8;
    }
    if(call_found){
        sp = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, t_pid, spoffs, 0);
        // print sp ...
        call_found = false;
    }
    if(opcode == CALL)
       call_found = true;
}
```

Comment: But if you want portability to non-x86 ISAs, many use a link register instead of pushing a return address.  OTOH, many of those have fixed instruction widths.  There are other wrinkles, though, like MIPS has a branch delay slot so the return address is actually after the *next* instruction after a `jal`.  Of course this is getting very far from your title question.  What do you really need / want to do when you've found a call instruction?

Comment: lDebug's P command does some limited disassembly to figure out the size of a call instruction. This as implemented is only for 16-bit and 32-bit modes, but could be extended to 64-bit. Here is [the handler in run.asm](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldebug/file/f003ae1eb111/source/run.asm#l3330) that implements this disassembly. Here are [the ppbytes and ppinfo tables](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldebug/file/f003ae1eb111/source/debug.asm#l688) which are used to dispatch most of the prefixes and opcodes.

Comment: @PeterCordes As I expected this gets much more complicated than I would like. For now I just need the return address of relative (near or far) calls on x86-32, but I wanted to try to be as general as I possibly could. Retrieving the address pointed to by SP sounds like the best option.

Comment: re: update: a comment says "print sp", but RSP is *pointing at* the return address.  You need to PEEK at that address.  (Also, you wrote "return value", not "address" in your edit.)  Also, you have to do another SINGLESTEP while RIP is pointing at a call, to make it actually run the call and push a return address.  And it looks like you're only checking for a single `call` opcode.  Indirect call is `FF /2`, so you need to check 2 bytes (masking away other bits in the ModRM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ptrace doesn't have a disassembler in the kernel<sup>1</sup>, and the hardware itself won't tell you this until after the `call` instruction has executed.

If you can wait until after the instruction executes, probably your best bet is to `PTRACE_SINGLESTEP` then read the return address `call` pushed onto the stack.  (ESP/RSP will point at it<sup>2</sup>).

---

The other option is of course to decode it yourself (including any prefixes which might get used for padding, like when `ld` relaxes 6-byte `call [got_entry]` to 1+5 byte `addr32 call rel32`).  Either with a disassembler library, or by scanning through prefixes until you get to one of the `call` opcodes, then you have the length either from it (E8 `call rel32`) or from decoding the ModRM byte for an indirect FF /2 `call [r/m32]`.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call).

---

If you wanted portability to non-x86 ISAs, many use a link register instead of pushing a return address so it's not identical; you can't just generically deref the stack pointer with `uintptr_t` width.

And many of those ISAs have fixed instruction widths so you *could* just go one instruction forward instead of single-stepping and reading a register.  (Although many support a compact encoding with 2 or 4-byte instructions, like ARM Thumb, MIPS, and RISC-V).

There are other wrinkles on some ISAs, for example MIPS has a branch delay slot so the return address is actually after the *next* instruction after a `jal`.

---

Footnote 1: (fun fact: ARM Linux kernels used to have a disassembler with support for *some* instructions, so it could emulate single-step for you, but [that hack was removed](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-arm-kernel/2011-February/041324.html)).

Footnote 2: Even for hand-written asm with a `far` call, the CS:[ER]IP return address will have the offset part at the lowest address, i.e. pointed to by ESP/RSP.  Of course, far calls use different opcodes, so you could treat them separately or ignore them.

I'm not sure if it's possible for prefixes to override a size in a way that will get `call` to push a different-sized return address.  (e.g. 16-bit in 32-bit mode).  Probably not, and even if so it would only be a concern for malicious binaries trying to fool your tracer on purpose.  Even hand-written asm for GNU/Linux is vanishingly unlikely to do this for any normal reason.

Comment: Could you also  provide a short example for peaking the return value out of rsp using ptrace, I just tried and I got some weird addresses which I could not even find using objdump -D on the binary. It would be extremely helpful!

Comment: I do think `o16 call rel16` in a 32-bit CS would push a word return address, as you suggest at the end. But indeed it would be unusual.

Comment: @ecm: Yes, I tested and it does.

Comment: @Desperados: Due to ASLR you should expect that addresses observed at runtime have nothing to do with what's in the binary.

Comment: @NateEldredge I thought of that. But what sp points to right after a CALL is completely different with what I see in IP right after the RET. I am a bit confused (and probably I am missing something)

Comment: @Desperados: Probably better if you post *your* code.

Comment: @Desperados: Then your ptrace is almost certainly buggy (or else the kernel is), or otherwise not doing exactly what you describe; at the top of a function (i.e. right after `call`), `mov rax, qword [rsp]` would load the return address.  And `ret` would pop it into RIP; an empty function can consist of only a `ret`, and `ret` is how we spell `pop rip` on x86.  (The same applies in 32 or 16-bit mode for uint32_t or uint16_t addresses.)

Comment: I edited the question to show my effort to trace rsp right after a call